# Downgrade from my latest beta package to previous manage package

Tags: apex, managed-package, custom-object, beta-managed-package, upgrade

Good day everyone. I have make a manage package in salesforce. I've tried to install it to another salesforce instance, and it is running as expected. After that, I've tried to create a new fields to the object, new validation rule and etc. The problem is that, I accidentally upgrade my manage package into beta and use it to upgrade the app on the other instance. I've tried to upgrade my package again and try to upgrade the other instance but I encounter the error that I cannot upgrade a beta package. Is it possible to downgrade from beta package to previous manage package ? If I will uninstall the beta package, what are the things I need to do so that those fields and other things i've added in the other instance will not be deleted ? Please Help....

Answer (score 2):

You will have to uninstall the BETA package and there is no other alternative here.

Things to keep in mind

1.All the new fields you created on the managed objects will have to be deleted to allow uninstall

2.If you have added validation rules ,workflows or any other customization on top of managed package needs to be deleted and recreated

3.You should back up data before uninstall in case you need them for further testing

4.If you have integration set up on managed objects once new package is installed you will need to set those again .

Back up everything using ANT so that once you have new releases metadata you can restore all customization you have done before .

Comment: It seems like I dont have a choice . Thank you for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can create the new version of package and this time it would be Managed Released. This package will contain all the components (new fields) that you had added for Beta package.

You need to uninstall the beta package, if you have installed on some orgs as they won't be upgradable.

After uninstallation, you will be able to install new version of Managed Released Package and more importantly you can upgrade your package in future.

[Managed Packages](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.packagingGuide.meta/packagingGuide/packaging_uploading.htm)